# Yii framework not getting functions from library into controller (using class.php files)

Tags: php, web, yii, spotify

I am using a Spotify library called MetaTune and was able to do this easily in CodeIgniter but with Yii there have been some teething issues however currently it has started saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::searchTrack() in ....public_html/Yii/news/protected/controllers/NewsController.php on line 67
```

Howevever, the the function is there. The files in this library all have a **.class.php** suffix (e.g. **MetaTune.class.php**) and the libray files are all stored in:

```
yii/application/protected/vendors/Metatune
```

With Codeigniter I made an additional spotify.php outside of the folder and autoloaded that to my controller, but im not sure if this is necessary.

I have loaded it in my **config.php** with:

```
    'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'application.vendors.metatune.*',
),
```

Here is the **Controller** code:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
 $model=$this->loadModel($id);

$spotify = MetaTune::getSomething();
$hello =  $model->title;
Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.MetaTune');
$spotify->autoAddTracksToPlayButton = true; // Will add all searches for tracks into a list.
$spotify->playButtonHeight = 330; // For viewing the entire playlist
$spotify->playButtonTheme = "dark"; // Changing theme
$spotify->playButtonView = "coverart"; // Changing view
try
{
    $tracks = $spotify->searchTrack($hello);
    $tracks = $spotify->getPlayButtonAutoGenerated($hello);
}
catch (MetaTuneException $ex)
{
    die("<pre>Error\n" . $ex . "</pre>");
}

$song = 'tracks';

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

Please also see the code below where it has a function called **getInstance** which doesnt work well with Yii for some reason and Im not sure if I can change this as I used this to import MetaTune into the CodeIgniter controller without any issues.

Just a part of the **MetaTune.class.php** code:

```
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.Artist');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.Album');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.Track');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.CacheRequest');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.MBSimpleXMLElement');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.SpotifyItem');
 Yii::import('application.vendors.metatune.MetaTuneException');

 ....

 class MetaTune {
const CACHE_DIR = 'application/vendors/metatune/cache/'; // Cache directory (must be writable) relative to this file
const USE_CACHE = false; // Should caching be activated?
const CACHE_PREFIX = "METATUNE_CACHE_"; // prefix for cache-files. 

const SERVICE_BASE_URL_SEARCH = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/";
const SERVICE_BASE_URL_LOOKUP = "http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/";
const PLAYBUTTON_BASE_URL = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";

public $autoAddTracksToPlayButton = false;

private $list = array();

// Holds instance
private static $instance;

.....

public static function getSomething()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $class;
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

.....

 public function searchTrack($name, $page = 1)
{
    $url = self::SERVICE_BASE_URL_SEARCH . "track?q=" . $this->translateString($name) .  
    $this->addPageSuffix($page);
    $contents = $this->requestContent($url);
    $xml = new MBSimpleXMLElement($contents);

    $tracks = array();
    foreach ($xml->track as $track)
    {
        $tracks[] = $this->extractTrackInfo($track);
    }

    if ($this->autoAddTracksToPlayButton) {
        $this->appendTracksToTrackList($tracks);
    }

    return $tracks;
    }
```

If you have any suggestions I would be most grateful. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried changing 'application.vendors.metatune.*' to 'application.vendors.Metatune.*'

Comment: @Pitchinnate the folder is actually metatune/ and the file MetaTune but I have tried with similar names to no avail. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Yii uses lazy loading, it only loads the files it thinks it needs. So if there are stand alone functions that aren't part of a class you may have issues. Have you tried using the preload section on the config file?

Comment: @Pitchinnate I thought i had in the above bit with the import array... I have added additional prices of code I think it is the getInstance that may be causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize `$spotify` anywhere, and php made it into `stdClass` by default, since you were assigning values like to member properties using that variable, but it failed when you tried calling unexisting method on it.

Solution: initialise it before you use it

`$spotify = MetaTune::getInstance();`

Comment: I had this originally, however Yii doesnt like getInstance as it uses it for another function to do with file uploads, so I changed it to getSomething and tried using that and it didnt work.

Comment: what do you mean Yii doesn't like `getInstance`? it's method from `MetaTune` class, it doesn't matter in which other classes it exists as well, since you call it using `MetaTune::`

Comment: Ah maybe I mis understood the errors basically i am getting a page full of errors starting with `YiiBase::include(MetaTune.php) [<a href='function.YiiBase-include'>function.YiiBase-include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and then `#0 
+  /studhome/1/0908037/public_html/Yii/framework/YiiBase.php(421): YiiBase::autoload()
#1 
 unknown(0): YiiBase::autoload("MetaTune")
#2 
–  /studhome/1/0908037/public_html/Yii/news/protected/controllers/NewsController.php(59): spl_autoload_call("MetaTune")`

it cant find my metatune file, is  it because MetaTune.class.php?

Comment: rename `MetaTune.class.php` to `MetaTune.php`

Comment: Ok tried it and unfortunately its still producing the same errors, so does this mean it actually cant find the folder...There are other files in the library which are class.php aswell so Ill cheng them to see if it affects it.

Comment: If `MetaTune.class.php` loads other `.class.php` files, then you just need to rename `MetaTune.class.php` for Yii loader to find it, and `MetaTune.php` will load other `.class.php`, so don't rename them. But investigate why Yii fails to find `MetaTune.php`

Comment: Ok I found that it was another library that was getting in the way when I removed it from the config there were no longer issues. So I have one final question, what is the best way to get the tracks variable into the view file with codeigniter it was `$data ['trackz'] = $tracks;` then using `$trackz` in the view which was simple but Yii doesn't seem as clear to me and I have been tasked with comparing the two of them. Thank you very much for your time and clear explanations.

Comment: in Yii you pass variables using an array in `render()` method, for example in your controller you would use `$this->render('/view-file', array('data' => $data));`, after which you can use `$data` in the view

Comment: Ok thanks Ill give that ago, cheers. 

I forgot to add that it only works if I remove the .class bit from all the files. 

I believe that the Yii::import only accepts .php which is odd.